# Chart of how the mathematical spaces are related? (soft question)

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

When dealing with specific function spaces e.g. Sobolev, Hilbert, etc., I find it easy enough to accept the properties of that space and work with them; however, I have a hard time visualizing how these are related to one another (I'm sure some, or even most, are not).  For example, how is Hilbert space related to a vector space, and how does that relate to a vector field?  I haven't had a formal course on functional analysis, so forgive me if this is a nonsense question, but is there a table of some sort of which space is a subspace of another, or relations among the common spaces?  The chart in the back of Casella and Burger's Statistical Inference text would be of the flavor I am thinking, which is a trimmed version of [this](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/2008amstat.pdf) chart on page 3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A Hilbert space is a vector space (in general on complex numbers) endowed with an *inner product* and *complete* (as metric space) under the norm induced by the inner product. So a Hilbert space is a vector space, is normed and hence is a metric space (then is a *normal* space, with the language of topology) and finally is complete as metric space, so is a Banach space. (Note that is a metric space since a norm always induces a metric.)

For what concernes functional analysis, we can state that the most general family is that of *topological vector spaces* (TVS). (However, they are a small set in the greatest set of topological spaces). In the TVS, we can recognize the two big families of *metrizable TVS* and *locally convex TVS* (LCTVS). These classes intersect but do not coincide. All of the spaces of interest are subset of the intersection. A broad class in intersection of LCTVS and metrizable TVS is that of *Frechét spaces*. *Banach spaces* are the largest set of interest in Frechét spaces and, in Banach spaces, a tiny but very important set is that of Hilbert spaces.

Probably, in some book a similar table is drawn (even if I don't know one where such a table is, so to speak, a graphical object), but I think you can depict it by yourself with the preceeding indications.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't all that you want, but see the diagram https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/topvs.png in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8443/barrelled-bornological-ultrabornological-semi-reflexive-how-are-these-us.